# Java - how are Akka, Play, Vertx etc. applications deployed?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, server, akka, vert.x

I've been reading about some of the (relatively) new application frameworks for Java such as Akka, Play and Vertx. I can't find a clear answer however on whether or not applications created with these frameworks are deployed like traditional EE applications? That is, are they packaged as WAR/EAR files and deployed to an application server like WebSphere? I my mind, a lot of the WAR/EAR infrastructure was built with traditional EE apps in mind.

Answer (score 2):

In there default they are not deployed like normal EE Applications. These Frameworks try to simplify things and make writing code faster and easier and so they most of the time have there own deployment mode and bring there own web server. Also they follow more the Docker approach of having fat jars and be able to be used as micro service.

So from my point of view it looks like this (could be wrong I did not use them):

- [Akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/intro/deployment-scenarios.html) its possible to add to an WEB-INF/lib in an war file
- [Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production) native installer is recommended. They dropped the war possibility but there seems to be an [github plugin](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin)
- vert.x seems no support for ear or war files